# How to fix AJAX request on browser side unable to send data to local server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to send data to local server using XMLHTTPServer. However, I am unable to receive it on the server side.

I tried printing out the object that was passed through but the body of request received by server is empty even though I am passing the data after using `JSON.stringify(data)`. The server uses the data passed to talk to mongodb hosted on AWS.

**BROWSER SIDE:**

```
var cardID = 1233456789;
var data = JSON.stringify({ "Card ID": cardID });
console.log("data = " + data);

var url = `http://${serverIP}/findUser`;
var xhr = createCORSRequest("POST", url);
if (!xhr) {
  alert("CORS not supported");
  return;
}

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
    userData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    if (userData == "") {
      console.log("ERROR LOADING USERS");
      alert(
        "USER NOT REGISTERED. Contact Michael Hofmann to Register yourself"
      );
    } else {
      //window.location.replace('https://ha6017.github.io/link_table.html?cardid='+cardID);
      console.log("userData=" + userData);
    }
  }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("Woops, there was an error making the request.");
};

console.log(xhr);
xhr.send(data);
```

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
app.post("/findUser", (req, res) => {
  //console.log('req.body = ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  var card_ID = req.body["Card ID"];

  //console.log('finding user with card ID: ' + card_ID);
  var que = {'Card ID': card_ID};

  dbUtil.findExt("User_info", que, dbres => {
    sendCORS(res, 200, dbres);
   });
});
```

I expect the data from browser to be passed onto server side. The request body can see the `card_ID` as `1233456789` in the `req.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate your code, because I don't know what your `createCORSRequest()` method is doing.

I got it working like this.

**test.html**

```
var cardID = 1233456789;
var data = JSON.stringify({ cardid: cardID });
console.log('data = ' + data);

var url = `http://localhost:3005/findUser`;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState==4) {
        userData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (userData == '') {
            console.log('ERROR LOADING USERS');
            alert('USER NOT REGISTERED. Contact Michael Hofmann to Register yourself');
        } else {
            //window.location.replace('https://ha6017.github.io/link_table.html?cardid='+cardID);
            console.log('userData=' + userData);
        }
    }
  };

xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
console.log(xhr);
xhr.send(data);
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')

// use CORS
app.use(cors())

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.post("/findUser", (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.body = ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    //console.log('finding user with card ID: ' + card_ID);
    var que = { 'Card ID': card_ID };

   /*  dbUtil.findExt("User_info", que, dbres => {
        sendCORS(res, 200, dbres);
    });*/
}); 

app.listen(3005, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3005!');
});
```

Comment: Probably its because you didnt set Content-Type.
Try `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: I think he did not use `bodyParser`

Comment: @TomaszBubała I had added the body parser. The xhr.setRequestHeader was missing and it solved the error. Thanks so much to both of you :).